# allocating memory for parameters passed as double pointer

Tags: c++

I'm passing a double pointer variable to a function that allocates memory for that variable. The pointer is valid inside the function, but it's not outside. Here's snippet of my code

```
allocate_mem(XYZ** paVar){
   paVar = new XYZ*[10];
}

XYZ** a;
allocate_mem(a);
```

I'm not sure what mistake I'm making here. I appreciate if anyone could point out that mistake.

Comment: As a basic aside: you almost certainly should *not* be doing this at all. Good reasons to use a "raw" `new` are rare, and good uses for a "raw" array-`new` are so rare they make dragons and unicorns seem commonplace by comparison.

Comment: For readability reason alone, I decided to not use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to pass it outside, you need to pass the reference to the variable.
This way the variable's contents can be changed:

```
allocate_mem(XYZ**& paVar){
   paVar = new XYZ*[10];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want might be:

```
void allocate_mem(XYZ** paVar){
   *paVar = new XYZ[10];
}

XYZ* a;
allocate_mem(&a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try avoiding hand-crafted memory allocation alltogether by using a `vector`:

```
typedef std::vector<double> row;
std::vector<row> a(10);

a[1].push(0.5);
...
```